# Admin password from create server api response is not working

Tags: openstack, createinstance

I'm using Create Server Api ([http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-computel](http://docs.openstack.org/api/openstack-compute/2/content/POST_createServer__v2__tenant_id__servers_CreateServers.html)) to create an instance.

This api creates the instance successfully, and returns the response as below :

```
{
    "server":{
       "security_groups":[
          {
             "name":"default"
          }
       ],
       "OS-DCF:diskConfig":"MANUAL",
       "id":"c6d04159-9bfc-4ab8-823d-0d5ca2abe152",
       "links":[
          {
             "href":"http://testdomain.com:8774/v2/4fd44f30292945e481c7b8a0c8908869/servers/c6d04159-9bfc-4ab8-823d-0d5ca2abe152",
             "rel":"self"
          },
          {
             "href":"http://testdomain.com:8774/4fd44f30292945e481c7b8a0c8908869/servers/c6d04159-9bfc-4ab8-823d-0d5ca2abe152",
             "rel":"bookmark"
          }
       ],
       "adminPass":"aabbccddeeff"
    }
 }
```

In response, we recieve a password as adminPass. I tried logging into the instance from console using that password, but none of the username like admin,root or server name works. So I'm unable to log into the instance.

Can anyone please help me with which username to be used?

Advance thanks for any help provided.